# How is the right way to use ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently learning ASP.NET, and I have trouble figuring out how ASP.NET MVC should be used compared to webforms.

I usually used PHP to make websites, and had to learn a lot of things about webforms : postbacks, callbacks, web controls etc. But the way I understand it, all of those are not supposed to be used in MVC applications, which seems strange to me since those represent a lot of features of the ASP.NET framework. I would like to confirm the following :

- Should I forget everything about postbacks and callbacks when using ASP.NET MVC ?
- Should I forget most web controls ? (I mean controls starting with asp:). Most of them seem not to be usable because there isn't any "form" tag like in webforms.
- In that case, would it be right to say that ASP.NET MVC is a bit like well-organized PHP ? Webforms works in a totally different way from PHP because of the postback mechanics, but it seems to me that MVC applications can be designed pretty much the same way as PHP.
- Are .ascx user components still used in ASP.NET MVC ?
- What about the script manager, and the AJAX framework ?
- Should I use Javascript the same way I would with PHP ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I forget everything about postbacks and callbacks when using ASP.NET MVC ?

- Yes

> Should I forget most web controls ? (I mean controls starting with asp:). Most of them seem not to be usable because there isn't any "form" tag like in webforms.

- Yes

> In that case, would it be right to say that ASP.NET MVC is a bit like well-organized PHP ? Webforms works in a totally different way from PHP because of the postback mechanics, but it seems to me that MVC applications can be designed pretty much the same way as PHP.

- Not really

> Are .ascx user components still used in ASP.NET MVC ?

- No

> What about the script manager, and the AJAX framework ?

- No

> Should I use Javascript the same way I would with PHP ?

- Maybe

ASP.Net MVC is completely different from WebForms.

The comparison to PHP depends on how you use PHP.

Comment: Note that ascx user controls are cshtml files if you use the Razor view engine. You use them by calling Html.Partial("ViewName", model)